# What does the target-specific vairable not take effect in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, fortran

everyone

How to set different prerequisites for the same target when it belong to a different target. For example,
target t1 depends on file main.o and t1.o where main.o depend on t1.o (it's a module file in fortran, similar as a head file .h in C) besides its source, while 
target t2 depends on file main.o and t2.o where at this time main.o depends on t2.o together with it's souce file.

i.e

---

```
t1 : main.o t1.o 
main.o:   t1.o

t2:main.o t2.o
main.o:  t2.o
```

---

I wrote them together in one makefile, but unforturanatly, the dependece of main.o does not take effect. why?

--

```
 1    .SECONDEXPANSION:
 2   
 3    FC=gfortran
 4    PRJ = t1 t2
 5   
 6    all: $(PRJ)
 7   
 8    %.o:%.f90 ; $(FC) -c $<
 9   
10   
11    t1: tname = t1.o
12    t2: tname = t2.o
13   
14    $(PRJ) : main.o $$(tname) ; $(FC) $^ -o $@
15    main.o : $$(tname)
16   
17    clean:
18        rm -rf $(PRJ) *.o *.mod
```

---

line 15 doesnot take effect. why?

here are the source file:

main.f90

```
use eqn
print *,nam
end
```

t1.f90

```
module eqn
    character(10):: nam = 't1'
end module
```

t2.f90

```
module eqn
    character(10):: nam = 't2'
end module
```

---

Comment: What are you expecting line 15 to do? It declares that `main.o` has a prerequisite of the value of the `tname` variable. Does the linking command not use the right object files? (What output do you get from make?)

Comment: Like jujj said below

Answer (score 0):

`target-specific vairable` is actually working, if you run `make t1`, then `make clean`, then `make t2`(It works on my PC). But when you run `make` or `make all`, it's not. This is because there are multiple targes and only one target `main.o` is generated i guess(not quite sure about this part)

The dependency graph maybe like this when running `make` or `make all`:

```
 t1               t2
 |\              / |
 | +-> main.o <-+  |
 |                 |
t1.o             t2.o
```

check below:

```
GNU make does its work in two distinct phases. .....constructs a dependency graph
 of all the targets and their prerequisites. During the second phase, make uses 
these internal structures to determine what targets will need to be rebuilt and 
to invoke the rules necessary to do so.
```

and

```
immediate : immediate ; deferred
        deferred
That is, the target and prerequisite sections are expanded immediately
```

(From [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles))

Comment: First of　all, `make t1` does not work in my computer, it compiles `main.o` first, and echo error since no eqn.mod found, which means `line 15` does not take effect in  this case either. Second, you mean that such a way will not work essentially?  What you explained and the graph you draw is exectly the same to what I mean! To accomplish this goal, how to write the makefile?

Comment: For `first`, you can echo value of `$(tname)` in main.o's command to be sure whether `$(tname)` is set properly.  For `second` : I skimmed whole gnu `make` document yesterday, seems `make` don't support this kind of logic. One way i thought is to write separate `target and rule` for `main.o`, like `main-t1.o` and `main-t2.o`.